# How to add the values of dictionary with same keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list containing multiple dictionaries. Each dictionary contains exact 7 keys. But, the values of keys is mix of string and integer. I want to add the values of integer one.
 
Below, is my list of dictionaries: 
 I want to just add the values of vega, theta, delta, gamma from all the three dictionaries.

```
[{'option_type': 'Call', 'expiry': datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 4, 15, 20, 26), 'vega': 2, 'notional': 7840, 'delta': 1, 'strike': 520, 'theta': 5, 'gamma': 3}, {'option_type': 'Call', 'expiry': datetime.datetime(1995, 11, 14, 10, 25, 50), 'vega': 2, 'notional': 1930, 'delta': 1, 'strike': 1960, 'theta': 5, 'gamma': 3}, {'option_type': 'Put', 'expiry': datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 7, 17, 2, 30), 'vega': 2, 'notional': 5530, 'delta': 1, 'strike': 1520, 'theta': 5, 'gamma': 3}]
```

Comment: @Zetys didn't get you..

Comment: @RamanBalyan Perhaps show what you expect the final result to be.

Comment: I want all these dictionaries mentioned in the question with one extra dictionary containing the added values.

Comment: @RamanBalyan Give a concrete example. Written descriptions are too easy to misinterpret.

Comment: For ex. the list of dictionary I want to work on is: var1 = [{'a':1, 'b': "test", 'c':4},{'a':3, 'b': "test1", 'c':2}] and the output I want in the format: var1 =  [{'a':1, 'b': "test", 'c':4},{'a':3, 'b': "test1", 'c':2}] var2 = {'a':4, 'c':6}

Comment: OK, good. That's what mine does. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34849763/996114)

Comment: Thanks! It worked as expected :)

Comment: Great! If it solves your question, feel free to click the little check mark next to the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> data_set = [{'option_type': 'Call', 'expiry': datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 4, 15, 20, 26), 'vega': 2, 'notional': 7840, 'delta': 1, 'strike': 520, 'theta': 5, 'gamma': 3}, {'option_type': 'Call', 'expiry': datetime.datetime(1995, 11, 14, 10, 25, 50), 'vega': 2, 'notional': 1930, 'delta': 1, 'strike': 1960, 'theta': 5, 'gamma': 3}, {'option_type': 'Put', 'expiry': datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 7, 17, 2, 30), 'vega': 2, 'notional': 5530, 'delta': 1, 'strike': 1520, 'theta': 5, 'gamma': 3}]
>>> 
>>> counts = {'vega': 0, 'theta': 0, 'delta': 0, 'gamma': 0}
>>> 
>>> for data in data_set:
...     for key in counts.keys():
...         counts[key] += data[key]
... 
>>> 
>>> counts
{'gamma': 9, 'vega': 6, 'delta': 3, 'theta': 15}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you already know the keys whose values you want to add, you can simply create a lookup list while iterating through the items and adding them.

Something along these lines:

```
lookup_count_list = {'vega':0, 'theta':0, 'delta':0, 'gamma':0}

dict_list = [{'option_type': 'Call', 'expiry': datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 4, 15, 20, 26), 'vega': 2, 'notional': 7840, 'delta': 1, 'strike': 520, 'theta': 5, 'gamma': 3}, {'option_type': 'Call', 'expiry': datetime.datetime(1995, 11, 14, 10, 25, 50), 'vega': 2, 'notional': 1930, 'delta': 1, 'strike': 1960, 'theta': 5, 'gamma': 3}, {'option_type': 'Put', 'expiry': datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 7, 17, 2, 30), 'vega': 2, 'notional': 5530, 'delta': 1, 'strike': 1520, 'theta': 5, 'gamma': 3}]


for item in dict_list:
    for key, value in item.iteritems():
        if key in lookup_count_list.keys():
            item[key] += 1

print(lookup_count_list)
```

Comment: `sum` is a bad choice for a variable name because it shadows the built-in `sum` function. Also, this doesn't answer the OP's question: he wants sums for each key, not a grand total.

Comment: @PM2Ring fair point, this was a pretty quirk and dirty answer. I'll edit it.

Comment: OK. You're still not giving individual total, though. And now your shadowing the built-in `object` type.

Comment: @PM2Ring the question was kinda ambiguous as to which sum did it want. I'll edit my answer again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate and use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) method

```
sum_vega = sum(i['vega'] for i in give_dict)
sum_theta = sum(i['theta'] for i in give_dict)
sum_delta = sum(i['delta'] for i in give_dict)
sum_gamma = sum(i['gamma'] for i in give_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import datetime

my_list=[
    {
     "vega": 2, 
     "notional": 7840, 
     "delta": 1, 
     "strike": 520, 
     "theta": 5, 
     "option_type": "Call", 
     "gamma": 3, 
     "expiry": datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 4, 15, 20, 26)
    },
    {
     "vega": 2, 
     "notional": 1930, 
     "delta": 1, 
     "strike": 1960, 
     "theta": 5, 
     "option_type": "Call", 
     "gamma": 3, 
     "expiry": datetime.datetime(1995, 11, 14, 10, 25, 50)
    },
    {
     "vega": 2, 
     "notional": 5530, 
     "delta": 1, 
     "strike": 1520, 
     "theta": 5, 
     "option_type": "Put", 
     "gamma": 3, 
     "expiry": datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 7, 17, 2, 30)
    }
]

result = {}
for dict_ in my_list:
    for key in  dict_:
        if result.has_key(key):

            if isinstance(dict_[key], int):# For integers
                result[key] += dict_[key]

            #if isinstance(dict_[key], str):# For strings
            #    result[key] = result[key] + '' + dict_[key]
            # We do not sum other types
        else:
            result[key] = dict_[key]

print result
```